# Change button to image.Load app and display buttons error. KIVY, Python

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to display an image as an intro to an app. Every time the user runs the program, it should display the image, then when press, it should open a few buttons which are popups.

```
from kivy.app import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.lang import Builder


kv = '''
BoxLayoutWithPopup:
    orientation:'horizontal'
    spacing:10
    padding:5
    Image:
        source: 'appintro.png'
        size:100,100
        on_press:
            root.pop1()            
'''

    #Helpme:
        #title: 'Help Me'
        #content: 'helpme.png'
       # size_hint: None,None
      #  pos_hint: 700,320
     #   size: 250,100

    #Games:
    #    title: 'Games'
   #     content: 'helpme.png'
  #      size_hint: None,None
 #       pos_hint: 100,20
#        size: 250,100



class BoxLayoutWithPopup(BoxLayout):

    def pop1(self):
#        root.add_widget(HelpMe)
 #       root.add_widget(Games)

        helpme = Popup(title='helpme', content=Image(source='helpme.png'),
                    size_hint=(.8, .8), pos=(1,30), size=(200, 200))
        helpme.open()

    #def pop2(self):
        games = Popup(title='games', content=Image(source='games.png'),
                    size_hint=(.5, .5), pos=(20,80), size=(200,200))
        games.open()

        settings = Popup(title='settings', content=Image(source='settings.png'),
                    size_hint=(.3, .3), pos=(1,1), size=(400, 400))
        settings.open()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    runTouchApp(Builder.load_string(kv))
```

Can anyone help me identify what is wrong with this code? I'm trying to display an intro when the app is initialized, which opens the main page when pressed, but the image for the intro and images for the popups are not being displayed. I also tried moving the popup positions, it seem to not be working. please help me.

Comment: You have not imported Label and BoxLayout `from kivy.core.text import Label                                                                  from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout`, don't see settings and a few other things defined either

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use of a "kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager". Why do you define "Demo" if you don't use it? What does "super(HelpMe, self)" mean? It's a super object, which isn't used at all. Why do you display a button to open a popup on this popup?

Comment: @user3856011 thank you! the screen manager gave me different options, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a tuple as the `pos_hint` when it expects a dict. If you want to specify the position, you should use `pos` instead - so instead of `pos_hint=(1,1)` you would use `pos=(1,1)`. If you want to specify a position relative to the parent, you can use `pos_hint={'x': 0, 'y': 0}` for example.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It really helped. I revised the code.